# Display Headers in Infragistics ULTRAGRID when no data in table

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2005, header, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I am fetching data in  from an SQL table using a DataSet in VB.Net. When there is data in table, it displays the data properly in the grid, but when there is no data in the table, it only shows the UltraGrid's basic view.

How can I display the column names of the table as headings of the UltraGrid even when there is no data in Table?

---

Thanks for the reply, but I think the problem that JD is having is a bit different from mine - in my application the data got fetched properly from SQL Server. My problem is that when there is no data in the table, I want to display the columns of the table as the headings of the grid with 0 rows. This is not happening.

It just shows a message box saying that no data is found, and the UltraGrid shows as it does by default in the application.

Answer (score 0):

This is discussed in [this Infragistics forum thread](http://forums.infragistics.com/forums/p/15503/61008.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Do you know what the headers of the columns will be or is it dynamic based on the data in the table? If you know beforehand you can create the columns with the appropriate headers in an empty dataset and assign that to the grids datasource.

Answer (score 0):

I notice this same behavior when I manually create a datatable and assign it as the grid's datasource.  If the data table is empty, all the column header info that was previously set on the grid is lost.  My solution to this was to never actually give it an empty table, if I have no rows in my table, at least have all the columns defined.

```
DataTable table = new DataTable("fooTable");
table.Columns.Add("fooCol1", typeof(long));
table.Columns.Add("fooCol2", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("fooCol3", typeof(bool));
myUltraGrid.DataSource = table;
```

By never setting the grid to an empty table, you keep your header info.